# R coding for find greatest of two number?

Tags: r, na

I want code of R programming to find the greatest of two number.

I cannot anticipate how to do that.
Please give me a code in R programming to find out the greatest of 2 numbers.
I didnot get how to write the above code.
Any help to that would be highly grateful and appreciated.

Comment: Can you do that in another programming language ?

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html?

Comment: A very simple google search would get you this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
number1 <- 4
number2 <- 5
vec <- c(number1, number2)
max(vec, na.rm = TRUE)
```